# How to pass custom parameter in selector

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uikit

- I have an array of objects.
- Every object has an ID.
- I have a UIStackview.
- Every object is dynamically added to the UIStackview as an arranged Subview (a Stackview as well).
- Every Subview has a UITapGestureRecognizer.
- The Recognizer's action is a selector.

**How do I pass the object in that selector?**

The subview's tap gesture:

```swift
subview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector))
```

The function being triggered on tap (modified for better understanding):

```swift
@objc func addModelToScene(sender: AnyObject, myWantedObject: MyObject) {
        let anchor = AnchorEntity(plane: .horizontal)
        anchor.name = "modelAnchor"
        self.arView.scene.addAnchor(anchor)
        
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
        cancellable = ModelEntity.loadModelAsync(named: myWantedObject.mesh)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: {error in
                print("Unexpected error: \(error)")
                cancellable?.cancel()
            }, receiveValue: {entity in
                anchor.addChild(entity)
                cancellable?.cancel()
            })
    }
```

In general, the question is:

**How do I pass a custom parameter into a selector?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this inside the loop

```
subview.tag = arrayIndexOfObject
```

Then inside the selector method

```
@objc func addModelToScene(_ sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  let index = sender.view!.tag
  // use it to access the object from the array
}
```

Comment: what if I make the sender a UIStackView and write: let index = sender.tag

Comment: Selector of `UITapGestureRecognizer` must have 1 parameter of type `UITapGestureRecognizer` you can't change it as this will crash the app

Answer (score 0):

Why not target the message directly to the object in question rather than self? subview.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: subview, action: Selector))